# Hilbert's Hotel for guests with infinite string name

Tags: uncountability, diagonalization

I was watching this video [How An Infinite Hotel Ran Out Of Room](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxGsU8oIWjY), by Veritasium.

The video says that it is not possible to fit names made of infinite strings of $\{A,B\}$.

We know we can fit infinite people in the hotel, we also know that there solution that works and solution that don't work. For example if you have infinite buses with infinite people if we gave a room one bus at a time we would be full after the first bus, on the other hand if we make a matrix and translate the diagonal to a single line (as shown on the video) we can fit everyone.

Following this if we ignore the name and treat the set as a stack then you would fit all of them because it's then a infinite stack and we can use their hotel room number to identify them, would this not be a possible solution?

Comment: This question about set theory fits the scope of [math.se].

Comment: @Yuval Filmus interestingly I can't find anything about stacks or queue in mathematics, it's combination of both but since nothing on stacks seems to exist in mathematics I asked here

Comment: That’s because your question has nothing to do with stacks and queues. It’s about elementary set theory, most of all about the definition of a countable set and Cantor’s diagonal argument. I’m sure you can find scores of questions about this topic on [math.se].

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if you have a stack based hotel where each room are stacked, hence you have to go from room $1$ to room $n$, you can fit another infinite stack onto this hotel including $\mathbb{R}$ is this then a different infinity or different data structure?

Comment: I suggest reviewing a formal treatment of set-theoretic cardinality. It should answer all your questions. Stacks and queues won’t get mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An infinite string is uniquely identified by a function $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{A,B\}$, such that $s(n)$ is the $n$'th character in the string.

The number of such functions is known to be: $|\{A,B\}|^{|\mathbb{N}|}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Now, its also known that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$, and hence there is no way to assign strings to hotel rooms, and more formally:

there is no one-to-one function between the set of all strings, (denoted $\{A,B\}^\omega$) and $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: if your doing $s(n)$ you are treating it as a list hence claiming countability I'm saying to treat it as a stack, which can store uncountable set and uses FILO method which does not rely on indexing

Comment: There is no "stack", "list", or "FILO" notions being used here. A function is a function, its not a list, nor a stack. Also, I don't think you understood what $s(n)$ represents. $s$ is a function representing a *single* string, not multiple strings. $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{A,B\}$ is the set of all such functions, hence it represents the set of all infinite strings.

Comment: I see now $s(n)$ is a single string. What I was referring to as stack and list was the set of all values created by the function. While it is known that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$ that is due to using a matrix, on my question I gave an example of solution that gives incorrect solution when trying to solve problem for "infinite buses with infinite people". If you do it one bus at a time you would have $|P(N)| > \aleph_0$, however if you construct a diagonal you have $|P(N)| = \aleph_0$ hence the answer depends on the method you use

Comment: A infinite matrix is structure that can store a countable infinite set of a countable infinite set, the reason why it is countable is because you can get a specific value using the index, however the set is a uncountable set of countable infinite values. A stack/queue can store uncountable set of constable infinite, it is uncountable because you can not get a specific value by index without removing and adding each before it. This is why you can make it work using a stack but not using a infinite matrix, hence it is solvable if you use the right method

Comment: The only reason why $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$ is true is because you use Cantor's diagonal argument. Why do you believe $|P(\mathbb{N})| = \aleph_0$, you can prove this is not true by constructing a matrix from $P(\mathbb{N})$ and go row by row mapping each person to a number i.e let $\mathbb{S}$ be the matrix of $P(\mathbb{N})$ where $\mathbb{S}_{xy}$ is the value on the matrix at row $x$ and column $y$ then you can match each column at row $x$ to a Natural number $1\rightarrow \mathbb{S}_{x1}$, $2\rightarrow \mathbb{S}_{x2}$, $3\rightarrow \mathbb{S}_{x3}$,...

Comment: Using the above method you will only map row $x$ this would prove $|P(\mathbb{N})| > \aleph_0$, is there anything mathematically wrong with this proof?

Comment: Its totally true that $|P(\mathbb{N})|>\aleph_0$, I just don't understand how you try to map infinite strings to hotel numbers

Comment: Did I get the notation wrong, how do you write infinite bus with infinite people, is this not $P(\mathbb{N})$?
If you put the infinite map of infinite string in a stack it will be able to contain all of them because unlike a matrix you can only see what is at the top of the stack and not the full list you see with the infinite matrix. Then you can assign a number to each person as you remove from the top of the stack, this would be a one to one relationship and would map everyone, but I don't know how stack are represented mathematically. Do you understand it now?

Comment: Mathematically, $P(\mathbb{N})$ is defined in the following way: $P(\mathbb{N})=\{A\mid A\subseteq \mathbb{N}\}$. The "infinite bus with infinite people" problem is defined as $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, which means that it shows $\aleph_0\times \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$. It has nothing to do with $P(\mathbb{N})$, that has $|P(\mathbb{N})|=2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: ok, I got the notation wrong did you look at the example I gave with $\mathbb{S}$ and how by mapping all values on row $x$: $1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}_{x1}$, $2 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}_{x2}$, $3 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}_{x3}$,... would show $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} > \aleph_0$. I'm trying to show that changing the method will give you different result but the proof should still be valid for both, right?

Comment: Showing $a>b$ for $a=|A|, b=|B|$ means showing that $a\ge b$, and also showing that $a\neq b$. To show $a\neq b$ you have to show there *doesnt* exist an invertible mapping between $A$ and $B$. Showing for a specific function that it isn't invertible isn't good enough.

Comment: That is true with finite set with infinite set you can prove all directions.  map one row at a time: $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} > \aleph_0$, map every diagonal to a natural number:  $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} = \aleph_0$, map ever diagonal to even number:  $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} < \aleph_0$. Why would we then say it is only $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} = \aleph_0$?

Comment: 1) $\mathbb{N}$ is a set, and $\aleph_0$ is a cardinality, you cant compare them. I guess you meant $|\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}|$ everywhere. 2) It is well known that $|\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$. This an equality, it does not depend on which function you chose. Its not how it works. 3) Since $|\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$, then there **exists** an invertible function from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. It doesn't mean anything about the existence \ inexistence of non-invertible functions.

Comment: Take a look at this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Comparing_sets

Comment: I've accepted your answer because even with the stack the cardinality would still be $2^{\aleph_0}$, hence you will only fit $\aleph_0$ of the set, you would have to have stacked (any other non numbered or $\mathbb{R}$ numbered) rooms to fit all of them

Comment: Yes, this is the point. The cardinality is bigger than the cardinality of the natural numbers, so you will never be able to put them in rooms (with natural numbers as indices).

Answer (score -1):

There is, in fact, a solution. Convert the name to a binary number such that A=1 and B=0.

Then, either subtract each person’s name from infinite 1111111 or just remove all 0s before the first 1. Either way, the set becomes all binary numbers from 0 -> infinity.

At that point, just add 1 and convert to decimal. Then you have all decimal numbers 1 -> infinity.

You can use the trick in Veritasium’s video to move all current occupants to double their number, then take all ABBA’s friends and take their name-based number • 2 - 1 to make a set of odd numbers 1 -> infinity and now they all have rooms based on their original names.

For my video about this:
https://youtu.be/o1JXUKhUzh4

Comment: What binary number do you get when you subtract 101010101.... from 11111111.....?